# Dictionary as function return type

Tags: ios, swift

I'm following a [RW tutorial to learn about Swift](http://www.raywenderlich.com/74904/swift-tutorial-part-2-simple-ios-app) and I'm getting errors at the first line of the following function declaration:

```
func returnPossibleTips() -> [Int: Double] {
    let possibleTipsInferred = [0.15, 0.18, 0.20]
    let possibleTipsExplicit:[Double] = [0.15, 0.18, 0.20]

    var retval = [Int: Double]()
    for possibleTip in possibleTipsInferred {
        let intPct = Int(possibleTip*100)
        retval[intPct] = calcTipWithTipPct(possibleTip)
    }
    return retval
}
```

These are the errors:

- Expected type for function result
- Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'
- Expected declaration
- Expected '{' in body of function declaration

Comment: Your code compiles well in my test project (when I remove unknown function calcTipWithTipPct). I think you should search syntax errors outside function implementation

Answer (score 13):

It's looks like you are not using last version of Swift (beta 5), in first versions there was no [Int] syntax for arrays.

you can update Xcode or rewrite this code:

```
func returnPossibleTips() -> Dictionary<Int, Double> {
    let possibleTipsInferred = [0.15, 0.18, 0.20]
    let possibleTipsExplicit:Array<Double> = [0.15, 0.18, 0.20]

    var retval = Dictionary<Int, Double>()
    for possibleTip in possibleTipsInferred {
        let intPct = Int(possibleTip * 100)
        retval[intPct] = calcTipWithTipPct(possibleTip)
    }

    return retval
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try to update XCode. I actually just downloaded it straight from the developer portal yesterday, I'll try again.